# HTC One V Bluetooth low energy api support

Tags: sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop application related with Bluetooth low energy for my HTC One V.

As HTC One V contain qualcomm chipset, Broadcom Bluetooth low energy SDK will support it? and if broadcom doesn't support for it then what should i do? Which SDK should I use??

Answer (score 0):

No.
Broadcom Open Source Bluetooth Low Energy SDK / API will not work on phones with Qualcomm chipsets. Neither will it work on phones with TI chipset. It's not likely to work on phones with Broadcom chipset's either since they don't include the required "Share Object" .SO file. There are ways to include the .so file from more native tools than eclipse. There IS a guide somewhere telling how to include the .so file from newer Eclipse versions but that requires you find the .so file.
It seems all the big chip-producers are fighting and destroying Android from within. Only HTC got an official BLE API and that is only from newest HTC ONE X+ and future phones.
Google announced in December that "BLE is the next big thing we will include" but that is over 1 year too late. Even Microsoft Windows Phone 8 might get BLE API's before Android get an official one :-(

I work with BLE support on HTC ONE X+
There used to be also an API for Motorola RAZR but it disappeared from their support pages. Too bad because I bought RAZR just for BLE development.
We had big hopes that Galaxy S2 would work with Broadcom "Open Source" API's but Broadcom never "blessed" this big selling phone with the .SO included in the firmware :-(
For Samsung Galaxy S3 there is at least unofficial API for scanning and discovery of BLE peripherals and services/characteristics but it kind of stops there. The rest seems not to be working. Summer of 2012 Samsung promised to be fixing the problems but they never did.

Maybe this farce is due to big political play of NFC v.s. BLE for various Micropayment systems. BIIIG MONEY for the one who gets the right ecosystem. Unfortunately this fight is killing the BLE peripheral business, only iOS and Windows 8 (not yet Windows Phone 8) got nice BLE APIs.